# Вывод рандомного числа, при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Как вывести кнопку, при нажатии на которую выводится случайное число, но кнопка при этом не исчезает?

Я понимаю, почему она исчезает- из-за `document.write`, но я не хочу использовать `alert` или подобные способы вывода, при которых открывается диалоговое окно или новая вкладка.

Помогите, пожалуйста, усовершенствовать мой код:

```js
function Random (){ 
    var max = 100; 
    document.write( Math.round(Math.random() * max ));
}
```

```html
<p>
  <input type="button" value="Число" onclick="Random()">
</p>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Не используйте document.write - пишите в какой-нибудь div, например:

```js
function Random (){ 
 const max = 100;
 return Math.round(Math.random() * max );
}

const btn = document.getElementById('button');
const div = document.getElementById('div');

btn.onclick = function() {
  div.innerHTML = Random();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Число" id="button">
<div id="div"></div>
```

Comment: мне понравилось но можно еще сократить код :)

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, всегда можно сделать лучше :)) например, не писать отдельно функцию Random и вызывать её, а сразу всё делать "на лету" по клику

Comment: согласен ))поставил плюс

Comment: Здравствуйте у меня почему-то `btn.onclick = function() { div.innerHTML = Random(); }` вызывает ошибку

Comment: @AhmadAkhmadaliev, а какую именно ошибку? Текст её приведите